# The grader doesn't calculate output correctly

Tags: python, edx

I am currently working on the problem in the edX Python course and the goal is to create a game like "Scrambler". I am on the step of "playHand" which is basically an interaction with player/user, which is outputting a score after each of the word is given as an input.

I have coded up the whole process and it works perfectly in the online compiler (python tutor). However, when I enter the same code into the IDE in on the course site, which should grade my answer and test it's own examples, the correct result comes up only at the first test (the score matches expected one). When the second test is passed the score is cumulated on the score of previous test, therefore making it bigger than needed.

```py
# some of the helper functions are dropped out from this code (but can be provided if needed)

# worldList is the list of words that are valid


single_period=["."]
score=0
def playHand(hand, wordList, n):

    while calculateHandlen(hand) > 0:
        global score

        if n<calculateHandlen(hand):
            print("n should be bigger than number of letters in the hand")
            break

        print("Current Hand: ",end =" ")
        displayHand(hand)

        word = input("Enter word, or a " + '"." ' + "to indicate that you are finished: ")

        if word in single_period:
            print("Goodbye! Total score: "+str(score)+" points") 
            break
        else:
            if isValidWord(word, hand, wordList)!=True:
                print("Ivalid word, please try again.")
                print('')  
            else:
                word_score=getWordScore(word, n)
                score=score+getWordScore(word, n)
                print("'"+str(word)+"'"+" earned "+str(word_score)+" points."+" Total: "+str(score)+" points")
                hand=updateHand(hand, word)
        if calculateHandlen(hand)==0:
            print("Run out of letters. Total score: "+str(score)+" points.")
```

So for example the first  test is:

```
Function call: playHand({i: 1, k: 1, l: 1, m: 1})'<edX internal wordList>', 4
```

my output is (CORRECT):

```
Current Hand:  k i m l 
Enter word, or a "." to indicate that you are finished: milk
'milk' earned 90 points. Total: 90 points
Run out of letters. Total score: 90 points.
None
```

The second test is:

```
Function call: playHand({a: 1, z: 1})'<edX internal wordList>', 2
```

my output is (INCORRECTLY OVER-CUMULATED):

```
Current Hand:  z a 
Enter word, or a "." to indicate that you are finished: zo
Ivalid word, please try again.

Current Hand:  z a 
Enter word, or a "." to indicate that you are finished: za
'za' earned 72 points. Total: 162 points
Run out of letters. Total score: 162 points.
None

*** ERROR: Failing on scoring the word.
Expected '" za " earned 72  points. Total:  72  points'
Got ''za' earned 72 points. Total: 162 points' ***
```

So, as it is seen, the test takes the score from the previous test (90) and instead of "zeroing", uses it as a new basis for the second test (90+72=162) and etc...

Has anyone had this course or have any idea how to tackle this?

Comment: score is a global variable, try putting it inside your function so that each time the function is called the score will be set to 0 then calculated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like they are not expecting you to accumulate points over hands.

I guess the IDE is calling `playHand` multiple times, you keep the hand score in the score variable which is the global one (`global score`) which is set to 0 only once and outside your function.

You can solve the problem making:

```
print("'"+str(word)+"'"+" earned "+str(word_score)+" points."+" Total: "+str(score)+" points")
```

this:

```
print("'"+str(word)+"'"+" earned "+str(word_score)+" points."+" Total: "+str(word_score)+" points")
```

Or resetting to 0 `score` at the beginning of `playHand`.